# Joining point layer with line layer using coordinates

Tags: qgis, point, line, attribute-joins

I am using QGIS 3.14, and I want to represent a road network.

I had a polyline layer (3257 entities) as a background. For each one I have calculated `x_start`, `y_start`, `x_end`, `y_end` coordinates, length of each line and other elements.

I have also created a point layer with every start point (3257 entities) in which I also calculated x, y for each point. I did the same for the 3257 end points.

These point layers have also altitude information which I extracted from a DEM. I want to transfer this altitude information to line layer.

I tried to use `JOIN ATTRIBUTES BY FIELD VALUE` and used `x_start (line layer)` and `x (start point layer)` as "key", and did the same with `x_end (line layer)` and `x(end point layer)`, in order each line afterwards to have the correct altitude of its startpoint and endpoint. But result is correct for some only of the lines (I checked it via excel).

What have I done wrong?

Comment: Have you tried `join attributes by location`? If so, how is the result not satisfactory?

Comment: Screenshots would help me visualize the problem!

Comment: 3.14?  Qgis.org shows 3.10 as the latest version.

Comment: I have tried to join attributes by location checking "intersect", but does not work properly for each road segment.

Comment: I have tried to 1) join attributes by location checking "intersect", 2) simple join to the line layer, attaching to it the 2 point layers using as join field either x or y of start and end points, respectively, and 3) join by field value, using x_start (of line layer) and x of start points layer, but y is not corresponding, even though joining is correct (x_start of line is the same with x of startpoints layer, but y is the same in some cases, and completely different in others. So I cannot be sure if the altitude given to each feature is correct, so as to calculate the slope of each segment.

Answer (score 1):

Nothing ensures in a network that two nodes cannot have one of its coordinates the same.

The joining process will be right if done between unique field values.

---

If your layers are GeoPackage layers, use the *'fid'* field for the joining. Make sure that you transfer that field values when extract the start and end points of each geometry.

Then, use the *Joining Attributes by Field Value* tool, but using the *'fid'* (or other unique) field as key.